# ScrollView and ListView to scroll Individually

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-scrollview, android-scroll

this question is in co-relation with my previous question

[Android listview not scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276138/android-listview-not-scrolling/12279990#12279990)

if its possible to use ScrollView and ListView in a single layout with their own individual scrollbars

Comment: see my previous question i have specified in this , no answer is correct,,, whatever the comments i find useful , i have given a like on them ... if i like the answer useful , i will definitely promote the guy

Answer (score -2):

Yes u can show both at the same time.But it won't make any difference.But if u want to view it differently  u need to make changes in the xml accordingly like.. changing its height `android:layout_height="120"`

Comment: You can use fragment to view both at the same time

Comment: use fragment to view the scroll view & listview